# Reclaiming space from a small but heavily used MySQL 8 table

Tags: mysql, innodb, diskspace, mysql-8.0

I have a production mysql 8 server that has a table for user sessions for a PHP application. I am using innodb_file_per_table. The table is small at any given time (about 300-1000 rows), but rows are constantly being deleted and added. Without interference, the sessions.ibd file slowly grows until it takes up all available disk space. This morning, the table was 300 records and took up over 90GB. This built up over the long term (months).

Running OPTIMIZE TABLE reclaims all of the disk space and brings the table back under 100M. An easy solution would be to make a cron script that runs OPTIMIZE TABLE once a week during our maintenance period. Another proposed suggestion is to convert the table to a MyISAM table, since it doesn't really require any of the features of InnoDB. Both of these solutions should be effective, but they are table specific and don't protect against the general problem. I'd like to know whether there is a solution to this problem that involves database configuration.

Here are the non-default innodb configuration options that we're using:

```
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 24G
innodb-log-file-size = 512M
innodb-buffer-pool-instances = 8
```

Are there other options we should be using so that the sessions.ibd file doesn't continually grow?

Here is the CREATE TABLE for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` mediumtext,
  `expires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In addition to additions and subtractions, the data column is updated often.

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM would have a different problem -- fragmentation.  After a delete, there is a hole in the table.  The hole is filled in first.  Then a link is made to the next piece of the record.  Eventually fetching a row would involve jumping around most of the table.

If 300 rows takes 100MB, a row averages 333KB?  That's rather large.  And does that number vary a lot?  Do you have a lot of text/blob columns?  Do they change often?  Or is it just delete and add?  Would you care to share `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I can't think how a table could grow by a factor of 900 without having at least one very multi-GB row added, then deleted.  Perhaps with the schema, I could think of some cause and/or workaround.

Comment: I've added the create table to the question. The data column is a serialized PHP string whose size can vary widely based on the user.

Comment: @paran - That's worthy of a bug report (bugs.mysql.com) -- Even if each of the 1000 rows had a full-sized `MEDIUMTEXT` column, it would take under 25GB, not 90GB.  It's as if off-row storage is never reclaimed??